# What does jQuery(empty object literal) really do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across this [article](http://markdaggett.com/blog/2013/02/18/javascript-jigs/) where I encountered the following line:

```
var o = jQuery({});
```

If did `typeof o` it says `"object"`. However, this object when consoled shows:

```
Object[Object {}]
```

Can anyone try to explain what is going on here?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just wraps a new empty object in a jQuery object. All jQuery objects have a `length` property, so they kind-of look like arrays. The library also keeps the elements or objects wrapped as properties with numeric indexes, so again it kind-of looks like an array.

So, after `jQuery({})`, you've got an object with a property called "0", and the value of that property is your new empty object. The wrapper object also has a "length" property, whose value is 1.

The jQuery library actually has fairly extensive support for wrapping its facilities around plain objects. That means you can attach event handlers to plain objects and trigger them, and other fun things like that.

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more :)

Comment: @Vikram answer extended.

Comment: I was confused about `{}` versus `jQuery({})`. Why have the latter for empty object when you can have former?.Ahhh I get it now...the third para(or the purpose of doing so) is what I was looking for...thanks so much!

Comment: @Vikram yes, wrapping a completely *empty* object doesn't make a whole lot of sense, unless you really do just want an independent thing for event handlers.